# Convert Byte Array/JSONArray to Base 64 String via APEX

Tags: apex, json

We are calling an External WebService that is returning us the JSON Object. In that Json  Object they are sending the PDF as ByteArray(JsonArray) not as Base64 String. So am thinking is there a way to convert that ByteArray/JsonArray to Base64 String that will allow us to make PDF in SFDC end.

Sample Response Json we are getting.(The actual Array is too huge, i have removed some array values just to post it here)

{"FINISHED":[[37,80,68,70,45,49,46,52,10,37,-57,-27,-12,-27,-16,10,51,32,48,32]]}

Answer (score 5):

Create a response Object like this

```
public class Resp {
    public List<List<Integer>> FINISHED { get; set; }
}
```

then do

```
Resp r = (Resp) JSON.deserialize(jsonString, Resp.class);
```

and then finally convert the r.FINISHED into a Blob

```
List<Integer> values = r.FINISHED.get(0);
String encodedString = String.fromCharArray(values);
Blob someFile = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(encodedString);
```

(Thanks to @Bachovski for pointing to the [fromCharArray](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_fromCharArray) function)

Comment: Converting the bytes to characters in 2 lines: `List <Integer> charArr = new List <Integer> {97,65};
String resultString = String.fromCharArray(charArr);`

Comment: Tried.. its Giving me System.StringException: Unrecognized base64 character: %

Comment: What does encodedString look like?

Comment: Encoded String looked like. %PDF-1.4
%ￇ￥￴￥￰
3 0

Comment: What happens if you do Blob.valueof(encodedString); ?

Comment: used Blob.valueof(encodedString); Its generating Blank PDF. No idea why.

Comment: Well, it's genearting a PDF, so it is able to read the byte array I would say. Probably the byte array really only *is* a blank PDF? Did you use the full byte array, or just these characters you posted a few posts back?

Comment: This solution worked. But the size of pdf was too huge that it gave internal error which was due to heap overflow.

Comment: Then the only solution is to write a streaming parser of sorts and be keen on memory usage. Or create an external converter, call it via a URL and get the PDF returned to you. Salesforce is not good at everything.

Comment: the given solution now doesn't work. I wonder SF's APi has changed in Between